# What is the Microsoft Graph Equivalent of Set-MsolPasswordPolicy

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

As Microsoft is soon deprecating the MSOL Module, we are converting everything over to direct Graph API calls.

Does anyone know how to accomplish the functionality of

```
Set-MsolPasswordPolicy
```

using direct Graph API calls?

Searched Microsoft documentation for anything related to:
"Password Policy"
"Validity Period"
"Notification Days"

I found one attirbute under the user object
"passwordPolicies"
[User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Result:
none of these turned up any endpoints that would accomplish what Set-MsolPasswordPolicy does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`Get-MsolPasswordPolicy` via Graph : `Get-MgDomain`

`Set-MsolPasswordPolicy` via Graph : `Update-MgDomain`

from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/powershell/microsoftgraph/azuread-msoline-cmdlet-map?view=graph-powershell-1.0#msonline-to-microsoft-graph-powershell